# How many 9patch images we required for android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using 9patch images for my app. I kept them in drawable folder not in hdpi, xdpi,.... But when i check the image in different density devices, it seems blur.

Shall i create the 9patch image for all htpi, ldpi, mdpi, xdpi ? If i'm using many images for my app,  i think app size will be increase. So not a problem to use many images?
Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to android developer docs , you need to specify different images

If you need to control exactly how your application will look on various screen configurations, adjust your layouts and bitmap drawables in configuration-specific resource directories.

**For example**, consider an icon that you want to display on medium and high density screens. Simply create your icon at two different sizes (for instance **100x100 for medium** density and **150x150 for high density**) and put the two variations in the appropriate directories, using the proper qualifiers:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   //for medium-density screens
res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png   //for high-density screens
```

Comment: ok fine. then what about size of app?

Comment: Actually, not all apps support all devices. You need to make sure on which devices you want your app to run and create different images accordingly. So, size would actually depend on how many images you use  and no doubt, app size would increase, but there is no other option. For more detail on it, refer to android developer docs for screens support : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Answer (score 1):

It depends

if you just want to prevent the image to be blurry, move it to the **drawable-nodpi** folder (create it if it isn't there), however this causes the parts in your 9 patch image which are NOT marked as strechable to be exactly the same pixelsize as in the image (thus looking different on different pixel densities).

if your have areas which should appear similar on all desities (e.g. corner radius), then yes, create multipe 9patch images and put them in the respective folder.

---

FYI: 9patch images are scaled to the the image density before stretched to the container size if they are not in the drawable-nodpi folder, causing a 9patch image to be blurry on a higher dpi device.

Example: you have a device with 320dpi device and a 10*10px 9patch image with 2px corner radius in the mdpi folder (160dpi), which you want to apply to your 100*40px button. Android will scale the image to 20*20px (including the radius to be 4px now, but appear blurry) before stretching the 9patch indicated areas to fit the 100*40px button.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is enough to have one image for all sizes. 9 patch image is stretchable to whatever size you want. That is the only use of 9 patch image. But you cant make all image as nine patch image. The unique images like lines, borders, plain image, etc. Why because you extract the image with some points only. So if you stretch the image depends some points the image should look like same as the image which how it look in small image.

for more details refer [here](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html).

I hope I expalined correctly.